# How setup and use libsvm in android mobile phone to recognize motions of the mobile user?

Tags: android, libsvm

I'm trying to identify human motion from android mobile phone.I will collect data from accelerometer and do some filterration to remove noise from data set .Those data used to detect human motions.  I have to use libsvm for pattern recogninition. I have no idea  how to setup libsvm in android and how to use it.can anyone give clue for this ?